# Setting element to width 100% to allow background to flow, but retaining children in 960px in center?

Tags: html, css

**Edit 2:** It seems clear that no one seems to be able to understand what I'm asking, so I'll try to illustrate it;

[image]

The area in the center has the id `#navigation`. This has the following CSS properties,

```
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
background: #e4bd04;
```

The reason it has a width of 960px, is because I would like the links in my navigational bar to remain within a 960px limit. I'd also like them centered, so I apply `margin: auto`. However, this means that my background only flows for 960px. I'd like the background to flow for the entire window width (100% of page), so that users with larger screens don't end a huge chunk of white space at the top.

In order to prevent this, I nest `#navigation` into another id, `#navouter`, to which I apply `width: 100%;` and `background: #e4bd04;`, so that the background now appears to extend for the entire width of the window.

Is there any way to do this without using two elements as I've done?

Comment: I've just tested your presentation here http://jsfiddle.net/7GTCc/ it works like a charm. What's your browser and what's the matter ?

Comment: I forgot to clarify, can it be done with a single element rather than a nested element (100% width, but contents restrained to a fixed width).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've undestood, you don't want to have 2 div to center another div with fixed width, isn't it ?

I don't think that you'll love it, but this is a solution :

```
.nav {
    width:960px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-480px; // width / 2
}​

<body>
 <div class="nav">Test content</div>
</body>
```

Result for 300px div : http://jsfiddle.net/7GTCc/1/

Or another, really ugly (lol) :

```
.nav {width:960px;}​

<center>
     <div class="nav">Test content</div>
</center>
```

**Edit regarding your illustration**

*"Is there any way to do this without using two elements as I've done?"*

No :-)

But if you only want the background to be 100%, don't specify a background (color or url) to your #navigation.

Last try to answer, test this :

```
#navigation {
    min-width:960px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/7GTCc/3/

Comment: The background for the class `.nav` is still restricted to 300px. I need the background to fit the width of the page :(.

Comment: euh..., if you want .nav to 100% why asking 960px ?? or put a min-width:960px that's all.

Comment: But I have a question too, why don't you want to use 2 elements ??

Comment: Additional markup, the question has kind of extended beyond what it should be into a big deal. I was just wondering, as it annoys be when I have to declare parent elements for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

you could use min-width property , dont know what exactly you are looking for

```
<div style="min-width:960px; width:100%"></div?
```

Comment: I'm looking to have the background for the element have the window width, while it's child contents to be restricted to a fixed width and centered.

For example, when you apply padding to an object, it retains it's `width` property, and expands on that.

Comment: ok got you, i dont think you can achieve this with one div only you will have to keep one for background , or you can assign your background to body

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is easy to do without additional markup. Use the `::before` pseudo-element for the expanding part of the navigation.

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/eAf7w/

HTML:

```html
<div id="nav">navigation</div>​
```

CSS:

```css
#nav {
    background: #6D7B8D;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;       
    width: 400px;   
}

#nav::before {
    background-color: lightblue;
    content: '\00a0';
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but no compatibility before IE 8